# React recaptcha constructor in useEffect runs before first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

Maybe I misunderstood the concept of useEffect but a I thought it replaces `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`, so its first run is after the component is rendered.
I'd like to integrate firebase into my react project, however it looks to me that the `useEffect` runs before the render method, because if I use it the following way, it gives me this error

> reCAPTCHA container is either not found or already contains inner
> elements!

```
const PhoneVerificationModal = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "...",
            authDomain: "...",
            databaseURL: "...",
            projectId: "...",
            storageBucket: "...",
            messagingSenderId: "...",
            appId: "..."
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
            'size': 'invisible',
            'callback': function (response) {
                // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
                firebaseSubmit();
            }
        });

    }, []);

    const [open, toggleOpen] = useState(props.open);

    useEffect(() => {
        toggleOpen(props.open);
    });

    const sendVerificationCode = () => {
        if (props.phone) {
            console.log(props.phone);
            let phoneNumber = props.phone;
            var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
            firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
                .then(function (confirmationResult) {
                    console.log(confirmationResult);
                    window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
                }).catch(function (error) {
                });
        }

    }

    const firebaseSubmit = () => {

    }
    return (
        <Modal open={open} key={open} closeModal={props.closeModal}>
            <div className={classes.PhoneVerificationModalInner}>
                <div className={classes.headerRow}>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.narrowCol}>
                    <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
                    <Button
                        className={classes.button}
                        rightIcon={Images.arrow}
                    >Continue</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

If I add delay with setTimeout to the recaptcha constructor, it runs without problem. So how is that the constructor cannot find the element, even if it was rendered due to `useEffect`?

Comment: Did you try console.log(document.querySelector("#'recaptcha-container'")) before calling RecaptchaVerifier, and see If the element exists in the dom?

Comment: @lissettdm it says its null. But how is it possible? I thought the useEffect's first run is after render, therefore the element should exist

Comment: Yes, it runs after first render, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mgcsdg. Try remove the code related to firebase, and see if it prints the item.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        toggleOpen(props.open);
    });, this will run everytime the component update, is that your wish ?  maybe the error could come from here

Comment: I think the error is inside Modal component, in how it renders its children.

Comment: try to move this <div id="recaptcha-container"></div> outside the modal component. just for test purpose

Comment: @lissettdm good idea! I moved it outside and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this over and over and this (invisible Captcha) works for me.

My method is to call captcha only when I'm submitting. useEffect is not necessary, and your captcha code doesn't expire if the user takes a long time to key in the number and submit.

You need to add this in your head. This provides the grecaptcha.reset function

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Create a onSubmit button which you should call when submitting.

```
   const onSubmit = async () => {

        window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('mycode', {
            'size': 'invisible',
            'callback': async function(res) {
                
                console.log('captcha code', res)
                //do your sign in with phone here.


            },
            'expired-callback': function() {
                grecaptcha.reset();
            }
    
        });


        window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function (widgetId) {       
            window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
            grecaptcha.execute(window.recaptchaWidgetId);
        })
        
        
     //https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#js_api

}
```

in your render you need to have the following

```
<div id="mycode" />
```

When you click on submit  button (after you capture the mobile/phone number), Recaptcha will determine whether a captcha check is needed. You will then get the code which you can submit to your backend for verification.

Comment: Hi, apparently the problem is related to the way in which the modal component renders its children.

Comment: your modal cannot use Portal, if it uses Portal it won't work. I have the same problem, hence I realise getting captcha code when submitting is much better than loading captcha when on page load. Your div with the id will definitely be there.